# Wrong answer when evaluating integral in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to compute an integral where the integrand is differently defined depending on in which interval we are in. So we have `f:[-1,1] -> R`, where `f(x) = sin(pi/x)` for `x` in `[-1,0]` and `f(x) = 1/2` for `x` in `[0,1]`.

Using Maple i get that the value of the integral is about `I = 0.04030`. However, in `C` I get about `I = 0.35829`. This is my own code:

```
int main(){
    double x,y,S_n;
    int n = 1000;
    int i;

    srand ( time ( NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        x = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX*2.0-1.0;   //generate double in range -1 to 1
        if(x < 0){
            y = sin(M_PI/x);
        }
        else {
            y = 0.5;
        }
        S_n = S_n + y;
    }
    S_n = S_n/n;
    printf ( "%f\n", S_n);
}
```

Can anyone see why this code is giving me wrong answer?

Comment: Always initialise your variables.

Comment: You should probably do `S_n = 0` before your loop

Comment: true but that doesn't change the result!!! how can this be so small with maple when there's 50% chance to get 0.5 ?? really I don't know. for me the C value is ok

Comment: please post your Maple code

Comment: I'm not familiar with your algorythm, but I can't understand how you can expect an equal result while working with random values.

Comment: that's the point of Monte-Carlo with enough iterations. Probabilities

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that definitely **does** change the result. The initial value of an uninitialized variable could be *anything*.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli of course, but in that case, I had roughly the same, so undefined behaviour, but with my float set to around 0, happens a lot with uninitialized floats 1e-38 or such.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre you can't make those kind of comparisons. You could get any value out of that uninitialized variable. It may be near zero or not, saying that it "happens a lot with 1e-38" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Your integrand is very ill-behaved around the zero, so no ownder you get arbitrary answers. The correct answer is appx. `0.731435`: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin(pi%2Fx)+from+-1+to+0

Comment: Both of your results are wrong. The real result is `0.731435`. You don't usually integrate anything this way, either take a nice grid or do proper Monte-Carlo integration. That said, your C code (once you initialise `S_n`) will be correct up to a factor of 2, which is the result of improper rescaling in the end (the average distance between points is 2/n, not 1/n).

Comment: In addition to the various C problems, you have a mathematical one. Your code works only when `y` is positive, because a new point should never _subtract_ from the current area under the line. However, `sin(π/x)` for `x ∊ [-1,0]` can be negative

Comment: Your MC is wrong, besides the fact that S_n is not initialized. You must multiply the function value with the size of the window : `S_n = S_n + y*(1.0 - -1.0)`. Then the correct value is around 0.75. I tested it against other simple functions.

Comment: looks like it requires either an answer or question closure.

Comment: Who decided off-topic ??? This question is clearly in the scope!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must

1. initialize `S_n`
2. take in account the size of the window to integrate on.

Thus the correct code is:

```
  double x,y,S_n;
  int n = 10000;
  int i;

  S_n = 0;
  srand ( time ( NULL));

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    x = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX*2.0-1.0;   //generate double in range -1 to 1
    if(x < 0){
      y = sin(M_PI/x);
    }
    else {
      y = 0.5;
    }
    S_n = S_n + y * (1.0 - -1.0);
  }
  S_n = S_n/n;
  printf ( "%f\n", S_n);
```

Comment: It does not work when I run the above code you have provided. The output is 10000 different values of S_n, and I just want one of them. Not sure if I'm supposed to do anything else after this?

Comment: Yes remove the printf in the middle... Need an edit. The last value is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does indeed make sense now when I look at the formula for stratified sampling. However, do you also happen to know how to compute the error of this MC method?

Comment: This is another question that is not in the scope of SO.

Answer (score 2):

Your code invokes Undefined Behavior (UB), since it doesn't initialize `S_n`, but then increases it by one in the loop.

So, when you declare it here:

```
double x,y,S_n;
```

you should initialize it too, like this:

```
double x, y, S_n = 0.0;
```

Then the values I get as an output lie around .36. If I were you, I would go back in my Maple code and inspect it really closely.

---

<sub>PS: If you are still unsure, then post a new Maple question, which links to this question.</sub>

Comment: I have tried to set to 0, same result. So only partial answer. I think the result is correct, maple version is probably wrong

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I agree, the output I get, is around .36

Comment: damn gcc doesn't even warn about this. I bet clang does.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre both fail to warn! Damn²!

Comment: even with `clang -Wall -Wextra` ??

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yeah!

Comment: where the world is going to?